# Chi-squared test using vcd package

Tags: r, statistics

I have a database where I measured if there was a relationship between two qualitative variables using chi2. Now, I would like to graphically display how the deviations from the theoretical model look (positive, negative, etc.). Thanks to my research, I found the VCD library that completely meets my needs.

I create my table

```
> (tab = table (data $ etat_sante_mental_bin, data $ area, deparse.level = 2))
                          data $ containment_place
data $ etat_sante_mental_bin In_the_countryside In_town
               1-VERY HARM 18 5
               2-MAL 18 4
               3-GOOD 67 28
               4-VERY GOOD 253 36
```

Here is the graph I have created so far:

```
> mosaic (tab, shade = TRUE, labeling_args = list (gp_labels = gpar (fontsize = 16), gp_varnames = gpar (fontsize = 18)), legend_args = list (fontsize = 16), margins = unit (3, "lines" ), legend_width = unit (7, "lines"), labeling = labeling_border (rot_labels = c (0, 0, 0, 0), just_labels = c ("left", "center", "center", "right") ))
```

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/22/73uj.png  -> Not very clean, but I'm pretty happy with the result.

Now, I would like to "paste" the corresponding row percentage value in the center of each of my rectangles. I saw on the side of "labeling_cells", but I do not know at all how to do it ...

Thank you.

Comment: Question should state: How can I add text to a vcd::mosaic plot?

Comment: Here's the documentation for the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vcd.pdf